# How to set in MSSQL studio a default number of rows to be shown with select * from

Tags: sql-server

Is there any possibility to set in Microsoft sql management studio in options a default number of rows to be shown with SELECT column  FROM table; ?
I know that I can write SELECT TOP(100) column FROM table;
But we have a lot of users that are used to work with Oracle where this feature is native and now they are consuming a looot with non-optimal selects of all tables. I am trying to find a "hard" workaround because even though we are saying them to use TOP in all of their analysis some of them are still not using it.

Thanks in advance for any advice that can help!

Default SELECT TOP(100) column FROM table when writing SELECT column FROM table;

I also tried this as shown at the picture, but it didnt work and the query result was still whole table. Even when I did change the time-out to 2 seconds it still continue to work..

[image]

Comment: I believe that the setting will only work on new tabs and not on already existing tabs

Comment: You can change the default `TOP` count to use when choosing to right-click a table in Object Explorer and picking the `Select X rows" menu items but there's no general limit

Comment: Forcing the number of rows returned, without the user knowing, sounds like a great way to end up with terrible analysis results. If the users are writing bad queries, then remove their permissions to write the queries and provide them with the tools to get the data that want "automagically" using a well-written query. Or, perhaps, the problem is that they have access to a production database, rather than a data warehouse, which along with impacting the results of other analysts is impacting your production application(s)?

Comment: I would also recommend providing (sanitised if necessary) backups and letting these users install a local instance and restore backups there. That way the only user they're hurting by writing inefficient queries are themselves. And you can use Dev Edition for that so no licensing costs.

Comment: Be aware that `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is going to produce arbitrary results, so expecting that you always get back the same X rows (which users will often implicitly do) is asking for trouble. Notably, you don't even have the guarantee that if the table contents do not change you'll get back the same rows every time you run the query. Such things are therefore not even suitable for most "analysis", unless you just want to very roughly see what's in the table.

Comment: We cannot take the privilegies away from them, its their work to make analysis and then they can write a nice optimized select. This is just for finding out the basics to make ETL. The problem is that they were working in oracle for such a long time that its really hard for them now to think about the TOP. I know that they will learn it someday but I am trying to find some solution now. I dont want to set it globally from the position of admin - preferably i would like to find something like the rowcount in the picture so they can choose themself what are they going to use.